# OOP: class inheritance to add just one property vs constructor argument

Tags: oop, inheritance, language-agnostic

I'm new to OOP and I'm in the following situation: I have something like a report "Engine" that is used for several reports, the only thing needed is the path of a config file.

I'll code in Python, but this is an agnostic question.So, I have the following two approaches

**A)** class ReportEngine is an abstract class that has everything needed BUT the path for the config file. This way you just have to instantiate the ReportX class

[image]

```
class ReportEngine(object):
    ...

class Report1(ReportEngine):
    _config_path = '...'

class Report2(ReportEngine):
    _config_path = '...'

report_1 = Report1()
```

**B)** class ReportEngine can be instantiated passing the config file path

```
class ReportEngine(object):
    def __init__(self, config_path):
        self._config_path = config_path
    ...

report_1 = ReportEngine(config_path="/files/...")
```

Which approach is the right one? In case it matters, the report object would be inserted in another class, using composition.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IMHO the **A)** approach is better if you need to implement report engines that are different from each other. If your reports are populated using different logic, follow this approach.

But if the only difference among your report engines is the `_config_path` i think that **B)** approach is the right one for you. Obviosly, this way you'll have a shared logic to build every report, regardless the report type.

Answer (score 1):

Generally spoken, put everything which *every* Report has, in the superclass. Put specific things in the subclasses.

So in your case, put the `_config_path` in the superclass `ReportEngine` like in **B)** (since *every* Report has a `_config_path`), but instanciate specific Reports like in **A)**, whereas every Report can set its own path.

I don't know Python, but did a quick search for the proper syntax for *Python 3.0+*, I hope it makes sense:

```
class ReportEngine(object):
    def __init__(self, config_path):
        self._config_path = config_path

    def printPath(self):
        print self._config_path
    ...

class Report1(ReportEngine):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__('/files/report1/...')
```

Then a

```
reportObj = Report1()
reportObj.printPath()
```

should print

```
'/files/report1/...'
```

Comment: Your pythons skills are more than acceptable! But I still don't see completely that this is the right way. Doing like this we lose the abstract superclass, and at the same time we got several subclasses. I think it would be better if there is only and only one way to create a Report object (this way you can instantiate the subclass, or the superclass passing the path). Then again, I'm kinda new to OOP and don't have the best grasp yet. Thanks for the answer!

Comment: My intention was indeed that the `ReportEngine` class is *abstract*, but I didn't know how the syntax for this is in Python. A quick search reveals that this is even not possible, but there is a workaround: http://www.boduch.ca/2010/04/python-abstract-class.html
Then again wich way you go depends on the functionality in the different classes. If your concrete ReportX classes won't differ but in the config_path, it makes no sense to create the hierarchy. If they differ in more things, you will be happy with the code due to separation of concerns.

Comment: In your example, I can instantiate report1 = ReportEngine(path_conf_1), and the object would be complete and fully functional. That somehow means that it is not an abstract class, right? By the way, Python does not have an abstract declaration, but this is the philosophy/culture of this language: you are an adult and you know what you do. And if finally you really want to, no protection will keep you from working around(with private variables happens something similar).

Comment: Then I fear the topic is not really language-agnostic. If you'd use a language with an "abstract class" concept, my solution were suitable. I'm afraid that I have no better idea for Python. You could stick to that OOP way anyway, and always use it correctly because you know what you do. But then there is not only one way to create a Report instance. I think you will have to opt for the lesser evil :)

Comment: Hehe, while you are strictly right, it is not the point I think. Isnt the definition of an abstract class, a class that can't be instantiated because of lack of methods and properties? i.e.: not complete. In your code ReportEngine is a complete class, and creating another extended class, using the constructor of the parent is exactly the same thing as just instantiating the superclass passing the parameter. I would say you have "the worst" of both approaches, A and B :).

Answer (score 0):

Basically the main difference is that approach A is more flexible than B(not mutual change in one report does not influence other reports), while B is simpler and clearer (shows exactly where the difference is) but a change affecting one report type would require more work. If you are pretty sure the reports won't change in time - go with B, if you feel like the differences will not be common in the future - go with A.